# REGEXP_REPLACE with DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I am trying to use distinct with REGEXP_REPLACE and 0 rows are returned.

I've created a test table in MySQLP v8.0

```
   CREATE TABLE phone(
   id serial primary key,
   phone_number char(25));

   INSERT INTO phone (phone_number)
   VALUES ('(423) 330-9999');

   INSERT INTO phone (phone_number)
   VALUES ('(423)3309999');

   INSERT INTO phone (phone_number)
   VALUES ('423-330-1111)');

   INSERT INTO phone (phone_number)
   VALUES ('1-423-330-6666');

   INSERT INTO phone (phone_number)
   VALUES ('1A423*330*1111');

   INSERT INTO phone (phone_number)
   VALUES ('5553301111');
```

-- Then

```
select 
   REGEXP_REPLACE(phone_number, '[^0-9]', '',1, 0, 'm') as clean_phone
from phone
```

--- works fine ->
clean_phone
4233309999
4233309999
4233301111
14233306666
14233301111
5553301111

--- count

```
select 
   count(REGEXP_REPLACE(phone_number, '[^0-9]', '',1, 0, 'm')) as 
   clean_phone
from phone
```

--- works fine ->
clean_phone
6

-- distinct clean_phone

```
select 
   distinct(REGEXP_REPLACE(phone_number, '[^0-9]', '',1, 0, 'm')) as 
   clean_phone
from phone
```

--- returns empty ->
clean_phone

I don't understand why distinct doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distinct is not a function  so you don't need  distinct() but only distinct

```
select  distinct REGEXP_REPLACE(phone_number, '[^0-9]', '',1, 0, 'm') as 
   clean_phone
from phone
```

.

```
    select distinct  clear_phone from(
    select   REGEXP_REPLACE(phone_number, '[^0-9]', '',1, 0, 'm')  clear_phone
   from phone ) t
```

if the bugs still remain you could try using an insert/select ofn a dummy table

```
  insert into dummy_table(clear_phone)
  select   REGEXP_REPLACE(phone_number, '[^0-9]', '',1, 0, 'm')  
  from phone;

  select distinct clear_phone from dummy_table;
```

Comment: I tried, still returns empty. Using this to test https://www.db-fiddle.com/ db:MySSQL v8.0
This works perfectly fine select REGEXP_REPLACE(phone_number, '[^0-9]', '',1, 0, 'm') as 
   clean_phone
from phone
Adding distinct like you suggested still returns no rows.

Comment: try not use db-fiddle  .. could be a bugs for this tool  ..  i have added  also  a test based on select distinct from subselect  ..  and last a test for based on insert/select on a dummy table  ..

Comment: i was starting to suspect a bug with db-fiddle! thanks for your help.